# Error Messages when tring to use MonthView control

Tags: excel, vba

My OS is Windows 10 Pro 64bit version 1909.
My Office version is 2013 pro (32bit)

I have a VBA project that contains few modules and userforms.
Two days ago something happened and the project cannot run the userforms that contain the monthview control.
I don't know the reason, but I think it's related to "Mscomct2.ocx & mscomctl.ocx"

The project still works fine on other PCs, with the same hardware and Office version.

The first error is "classfactory cannot supply requested class".
The second error is "system error &H80040111 (-2147221231)" and "Out of memory"

I searched for hours in google and other forums and still couldn't solve the problem.

1. I tried to repair the Office & uninstall and install few times without success.
2. I copied the ocx files from a PC where the code ran fine and pasted in C:\windows\syswow64.
   I used "Regsvr32" command as administrator

   ```
   regsvr32 "C:\windows\syswow64\mscomct2.ocx"
   regsvr32 "C:\windows\syswow64\mscomctl.ocx"
   ```

   I got a confirmation message but the errors still appears.
3. I tried also to do some registry changes.
   I search in the registry for "C:\windows\syswow64\mscomct" 
   and compared 2 of my computers.
   I changed everything like the PC where the code runs fine.
   now i get 2 other errors:

   - > Class Not Registered
   - > Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine

I hoped you guys could help me to solve the errors.

Comment: Personal Experience: Date controls do not work in 64 bit version of Office. You can use them on 64 bit OS machines running 32 bit office tho. There is no workaround. You would have to replace them all with custom controls you write yourself, or maybe find one online if you are lucky, but then you have to also distribute that to each machine.

Comment: Hey, Thank for your answer.
i am using 32 bit office version. i know that it cant work on 64 bit..

Comment: Try reinstalling Office 32bit.

Comment: I have done that 3 times, whithout any success.

Comment: That's about all you can do other than reformatting the machine and starting with a fresh OS and everything... unless anyone else has any ideas... I'm fresh out.